# click event being fired twice - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, input

I have the following simplified html:

```
<div class="foo" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
  <input type="checkbox" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.foo').click(function(){$(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].click();});
</script>
```

Clicking the 200x200 div 'foo' works well, and raises the click event for the checkbox inside it.

However when I exactly click the checkbox itself, it fires its 'normal' event, plus the jquery bound event above, meaning the checkbox checks itself, then unchecks itself again.

Is there a tidy way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: It looks okay in IE and not in FF.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Events bubble. You would need test the `e.target` that was clicked.

And if you're just trying to check/uncheck the box, you should set its `checked` property.

```
$('.foo').click(function( e ){
    if( e.target.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'INPUT' ) {
        var cbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0];
        cbox.checked = !cbox.checked;
    } 
});
```

**EDIT:** Fixed a couple mistakes.

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LhSG9/

Comment: +1 for both using chaining on the existing selector _and_ the very terse `false` form of `bind`.

Comment: @Phrogz: Thanks, but I had to change that because `false` also does a `preventDefault`. :o(

Comment: Doh! Well, your new answer fights with mine, so clearly I'm going to have to take my vote away. :)

Comment: Sorry about that @Phrogz. I was so busy trying to find the stupid bug in mine that I didn't see yours. BTW, looks like you have a similar bug, but the approach is right, so +1 on yours. :o)

Comment: Heh, I was j/k :). You still get a vote, and no apologies necessary. And you're right, mine is bugged. Deleting and adding a better answer :)

Answer (score 13):

How about this: instead of using a div, use a `<label>`. It's more semantically correct, does exactly what you want, and requires no JavaScript.

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LhSG9/1/

Comment: Definitely the way to go if at all possible.

Answer (score 11):

You need to stop the click on the checkbox so it does not bubble up to the div.

```
$('.foo input:checkbox').click(function(e){
    // will stop event from "bubbling"
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because when you click on the checkbox you are also clicking on the div because the checkbox is inside it. So what you should do is capture when the user clicks the inside the div but no the checkbox. If the user does click on the checkbox it will act with its default behavior checking/unchecking

```
$('.foo:not(':checkbox')').click(function(){
    $(this).find('input:checkbox')[0].click();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

include the following function in yiur `$(document).ready function` -

give an id say test to your checkbox then -

```
$('#test').click(function(){
return false;
});
```